# iOS Storyboard app + AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Can't get where pointed out in configuration files that my app delegate is AppDelegate.h ? Or maybe this name used by default always ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in main.m, the fourth parameter to UIApplicationMain() is the class of the application's delegate:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

}
```

An instance of this class will be created as a result of this call.

Answer (score 0):

Look at main.m (the call to `UIApplicationMain`).  The boilerplate there has class definitions.